# Bundle signing information - what are cd-hashes (or unique)

Tags: macos, cocoa, code-signing

I'm trying to check code signing information of a bundle from code.
The bundle is signed with a Mac Developer certificate.

After a bunch of trivial method calls the last of which is `SecCodeCopySigningInformation()` I get a signing information dictionary.

What I got from reading the docs ([kSecCodeInfoCdHashes docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/kseccodeinfocdhashes) in particular) is that the `kSecCodeInfoUnique` key of the dictionary contains a hash and the `kSecCodeInfoDigestAlgorithm` key contains the algorithm used to generate the hash. The same applies to the values of `kSecCodeInfoCdHashes` & `kSecCodeInfoDigestAlgorithms` keys.

But the algorithm returned is `kSecCodeSignatureHashSHA256` while it's length is `20`, which is coincidentally the length of *SHA-1*. This makes me think I got it wrong.

So what are these values exactly and how do they relate?

Comment: To clarify: the bigger problem I'm trying to solve is to manually check the signature on a bundle. Get the signature, the signed data, and verify it against a known public key. While the question may look like an example of XY-problem, it is not, as I'm trying to understand the whole topic in details, piece by piece. And I also think the question is pretty much self-contained. Cryptography is a hard business.